# embedding an application within a c# program with gtk#

Tags: c#, gtk, embed, gtk#

I'd like to embed a movie watching application like VLC into my C# program using the GTK# binding.

Googling, I haven't seen many solutions that people have claimed to be easy or that work.

Experiences? Help?

Please!

Thanks,
jbu

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for VLC but [Banshee](http://banshee-project.org/), a C# GTK+ multimedia app, uses [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) to embed videos in its interface. Maybe their code could help you.

GStreamer is cross-platform and has many plugins for most video formats out there.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use a GTK#? (this may have something to do with Mono, and if so, my apologies, I know nothing about Mono).

If you've got a C# app, you can embed VLC in it with one of the VLC wrappers. Search the VideoLan forums. For instance, this [thread](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=52021&start=15). I've been using the Marx wrapper myself in my C# app. Works well.